# How do i get the app launcher icon in plank?

Tags: plank

Im using plank and i was wondering how to get the app launcher icon from ubuntu in plank?

Answer (score 0):

the app launcher appear in Plank, when you open the app, but if you close it down it may disappear, but you can right click the app and click "keep in Dock" (sorry if its wrong)

Comment: thanks that is correct for a normal app but not for the launcher

Comment: sorry if that's not fix your problem :)